# "App Rejected" banner stays up on Google Play Console despite updates/modifications submitted

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Upon learning that the v1 of my app was rejected for metadata issues, I had updated the metadata and also submitted a new version of the app via release management. This was completed by hitting the "Resubmit App" button.

However, after doing both, I still see the banner staying up on the top of the Play Console:

[image]

Additionally, towards the bottom, the "Resubmit App" button is greyed out with the "Processing Update" arrow frozen:

[image]

Have I missed a step, or is this the normal process with the Google Play Console?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: Hey @TimCastelijns, appreciate the comment. I think its relevant as its not pertinent to the subjective matter of an actual app review, but rather understanding how to navigate the UX of the Play Console when faced with a rejection due to metadata, as it is not always clear. Let me know if this makes sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your app was rejected and you changed it, then it will need to be re-reviewed. It looks like the re-review is waiting to complete. If you wait it should update.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just to be sure, I am assuming this status will stay up even _after_ I have submitted the apk update/updates to the metadata until its re-reviewed again?

Comment: I believe that is true. When the review is finished it shouldn't say "Processing update" any more.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I've resubmitted game again and notice that status still 'App rejected'.
New information appears beside your app icon "Processing update".
It means that Google Play is processing review your app again and it's expected to have 'App rejected' status at the end of their review.

FYI: I'm waiting for reviewing my app 12 hours. So don't worry, it's expected. Keeps you updated.

UPDATE 1.

So now I have published game fully.

- It took ~24 hours from "**Pending publication**" to "**Rejected**" status
- It took ~24 hours after fix apk from "**Rejected**" to "**Published**" status

So it can take more that 2-3 hours as it's wrote in the documentations.
Keep eyes on the current status of your publication.

Comment: For me after updating apk or even after re submitting there is a new status comes "processing update", but after 1 hour it goes out.I don't know what to do, i can't see any status changed or any update why it is still showing rejected status?

Comment: Hi @AsadAli. It's OK to have `processing update` status. It means your update is in the process now and you will be updated of the result soon. For me it takes 1 day in average

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is that  "processing update" is only stays for 1 hour after thats its gone. and am only able to see "App rejected" in Dashboard.

Comment: It means that Google Play team rejected your app again. They should send an email with the explanation.

Comment: client's email is attached, previously there warning is shown in play console, but after new roll out there is nothing in play console

Comment: I had a trouble with messages come from Play Console. If the status is changed the email should be sent for sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with the APK, this is issue with "description" and title you have put in google play. make sure that it should violate its policy....

[Google play developer policy](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/understand-play-policies)

Comment: *it should violate its policy* - what?

Comment: I think you meant that it shouldn't :) Regardless, my question is that, *after* I have submitted the updates to the description, would I *still* expect to see this banner active?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have no active APKs in the Google Play Store that violate the policies. If you made a release that adheres to the policies, confirm that it is available as an active APK across all channels(Production, Beta, Alpha etc.) and de-activate the APKs that do not comply with the policies.